# My Sidr Menu is not opening on Chrome - on home computer only

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, sidr

Long time user/lurker, but this is my first time asking a question.  Here goes...

The sidr menu on http://jonathanfanndesign.com/lowsleep/ works on my home laptop on IE, works on my iPhone, works on my work computer in Chrome, and works on my wife's Mac, but simply gives me http://jonathanfanndesign.com/lowsleep/#sidr as the result with no menu being pulled out on my home laptop (HP running Windows 8).

The Developer area returns the following errors:

```
GET http://jonathanfanndesign.com/lowsleep/dist/js/slider.js 404 (Not Found) (index):128
Uncaught ReferenceError: MM_preloadImages is not defined (index):29
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

The slider javascript error is there because it is not being used anymore and I need to remove that from my code when I get to work tomorrow, so I didn't upload it to my site, but this shouldn't affect the sidr menu.  Could it be the deprecated event.returnValue?  Why would this not work only on ONE computer?  I'm sort of freaking out about this because I don't want my sites not working on random people's computers with me not knowing about it.

Thank you for any input you can offer.

Comment: Make sure your Chrome is up to date. I've tested here on Windows 8 (also HP), on my Chrome 31 and worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for testing it!  Will check that when I get home.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Chrome desktop (Version 47.0.2526.111 (64-bit)) the Sidr menu didn't open on Chrome. closing all windows and restarting Chrome did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this exact same issue that you were having. My Sidr menu was working in just about every browser except Google Chrome on PC (but Chrome on Mac was fine). I also noticed I was having issues opening the menu on mobile also. I would have to very delicately press the menu button for it to work.

I found a solution to both issues here:

https://github.com/artberri/sidr/issues/97

Essentially the solution is basically putting the menu icon within a jQuery click function below your original Sidr function call:

```
jQuery("#id_of_my_btn").click(function() {
    jQuery.sidr('toggle', 'name_of_the_sidr_panel');
});
```

You'll notice that I used "jQuery" instead of "$". That could also be a possible issue, especially if you have a CMS like WordPress installed with plugins that conflict with the "$". I have had to use "jQuery" instead of "$" on most of my WordPress sites.

Another thing to note is that I also had to put all of my Sidr code into the footer of my website, due to loading issues, which could also be another possible issue.